# PuppeteerSharp best practices

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Are there any best practices to follow when using PupperteerSharp? I've seen some properties like EnqueueAsyncMessages and EnqueueTransportMessages but can't find any good explanations on when is best to turn them on/off and if they make any performance improvements.

Also I've noticed in the ResourceType Enum there is Image and Img. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't turn those flags on unless you get stuck :)

- `EnqueueAsyncMessages` was created for cases where your code is not `async` all the way. I honestly dislike that flag.
- `EnqueueTransportMessages` is recommended on .NET Framework code because the websocket library behaves differently there.

Regarding ResourceTypes, `ResourceType.Image` comes from Chrome and `ResourceType.Img` comes from Firefox.

Comment: Am I OK to turn EnqueueTransportMessages off if I'm running .NET core? The default is true

Comment: Exactly. That will make your code slightly faster.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I do love fast code! Is there anything else that can be turned on/off to improve performance?